# what is the 'what' command on AIX under LINUX

Tags: c++, linux, version-control, unix

I am used to use what to find out some version string in my program, which is normal defined as a string in the c++ code, starting with "@(#)".

Now I cannot find it in Linux. Can anyone tell me what I am supposed to do? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `what` command is part of the Source Code Control System (SCCS), which is not commonly available on Linux (if there is a Linux version at all). You can try to emulate it with the `strings` command:

```
strings a.out | fgrep '@(#)'
```

Reimplementations of `what` are available in [CSSC](http://www.gnu.org/software/cssc/) (an SCCS-to-modern version control conversion package) and in BSD ([source code](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/what/)).

Comment: Thnaks a lot. I have to add --all option to make it really working.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
strings myprogram | grep '@('
```

Answer (score 1):

As @larsmans said, `what` command is part of [SCCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_Code_Control_System).  [Here is the link](http://www.gnu.org/software/cssc/) to the GNU replacement for SCCS

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the mention of SCCS, `ident` is the equivalent for RCS (and there are quite a few tools which use the same marker as RCS, CVS being the first one of these).

Answer (score 0):

The following command gives the most equivalent output compared to `what`:

```
strings filename |
sed -n 's/.*\"@(#)\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p'
```