# how to check /bin/sh version on Solaris?

Tags: sh, solaris

There's a "-version" option for bash, but not in "/bin/sh". Is there a way to check the /bin/sh version?

```
$/bin/bash -version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (i386-pc-solaris2.10)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
$/bin/sh -version
-version: bad option(s)
$file /bin/sh
/bin/sh:        ELF 32-bit LSB executable 80386 Version 1, dynamically linked, stripped
```

Comment: Have you tried `man sh`?

Comment: Just show the OS version:
SunOS 5.10           Last change: 2 May 2008                   21

Comment: Please share more details. How is your problem related to programming? And why do you still use am OS that is fifteen years old?

Comment: One can have a need to use old HW (and OS). OP does not have to disclose that.

Comment: What *problem* will knowing the version solve?  `sh` is not `bash`, and `bash` is not `sh`, despite Linux conflating the two.

Comment: Some ```sh``` script has different behaviors on different hosts, so I'm trying to figure out the ```sh``` version. I cannot find the ```version``` option. Even the ```man sh``` gives the OS info only. I suspicious the ```sh``` is the kind of bundled tools within the Solaris system.

Comment: It's Sun's version of the Bourne Shell. Does the command `what /bin/sh` give any output?

Comment: What shows the OS version

what /bin/sh
/bin/sh:
        SunOS 5.10 Generic 142252-02 Sep 2010

Comment: That's as specific as it gets.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the 'what' command on AIX under LINUX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122792/what-is-the-what-command-on-aix-under-linux)